# Error al crear un link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy creando un enlace para eliminar un registro de la base de datos, el enlace llama a un método destroy que es el encargado de hacer la eliminación.

Link:

```rb
<%= link_to "Eliminar el articulo", options = {:action => destroy, :id => @article.id}, html_options = {:method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => '¿Estas seguro?' }, :class => 'btn btn-danger'} %>
```

Routes.rb:

```rb
delete 'articles/:id' => 'articles#destroy'
```

Controller:

```rb
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Para ser mas conciso e de decir que puedo situar el problema en el link ya que lo que falla es `:action => destroy` pero si lo saco el enlace la que hace es ir a la misma pagina en vez de eliminar el registro.

El error: undefined local variable or method `destroy' for #ActionView::Base:0x000000000395d0

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás usando `:action => destroy`, como si `destroy` fuese una variable, siendo que debería ser un símbolo como `:action => :destroy`.
De todas formas, una manera mas simple sería:

```
<%= link_to "Eliminar el articulo", article_path(@article), 
            method: :delete, data: { confirm: '¿Estas seguro?' }, 
            class: 'btn btn-danger'} %>
```

Comment: De esta forma me redirige a la sección de la lista de artículos en vez de al root_path tal y como esta definido en el controlador, sigue sin salir el mensaje para que confirmar la operación ```data: { confirm: '¿Estas seguro?' }``` y tampoco elimina el articulo.